# utf-8 characters in imagestring() function

Tags: php, gd

I have problem with UTF-8 characters in imagestring() function,  i'm trying to write these chacters "აბგდევზ" on image. `imagestring($img,5,15,22,"აბგდევზ",$cor);`

any idea?

[image]

Comment: Images as well as code segments should be included and not linked. It goes a long way to make a post more readable. If you do not have enough reputation work it up, it is not that much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `imagestring()` doesn't support UTF-8 characters. If you need support for those, you need to use `imagettftext()`, which supports UTF-8, but needs to be linked to a TrueType font.

Here is the documentation for the function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php